# Grouping categories in hexo

Tags: javascript, themes, hexo, yaml-front-matter

I would like to group categories in hexo. While the hexo **<% list_categories %>** helper lists all my categories alright, I would like to group nested categories right.

My question is on two levels, first, how do you represent the subcategories in the front matter. In other words, how would I add the subcategories [motosport, cricket, basketball, hockey] into the following front matter. *sports* is the main category

```
categories:
  - sports
```

Two, how do I enumerate through all categories and each of their children. Do I still use this code

```
<%- list_categories(site.categories, { options}); %>
```

or is there a better way/function?

Comment: This theme support childCategories you could look how it's done https://github.com/LouisBarranqueiro/hexo-theme-tranquilpeak/blob/master/layout/all-categories.ejs

Comment: I checked it, and I still have a problem because there is no actual example of how you hook into that support in an actual project. I mean, how do you write the subcategories in the front matter?

Comment: Try `parent-categories: MyCategory` in front matter

on Categories-filter.js
`this.dataCategory = 'category';`
`this.dataParentCategories = 'parent-categories';`

Comment: Hmm, in the yaml. Look I want to publish an article under **category** sports, and **subcategory** cricket. How would you put it?

Comment: Then how would you reference this in the theme so that it works for all posts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In [Hexo v3.3.9](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/releases/tag/3.3.9) added [hierarchical categories feature](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/pull/2734). Need to update `hexo/node_modules/hexo/lib/models/post.js` by [this commit](https://github.com/danieljsummers/hexo/commit/a57f3c1b77b7c8ec8a3c785dcf8972e609582a2a) (or newer if exists). And set categories like this (in `*.md`):

   ```
   categories:
   - [sport, motosport]
   - [sport, cricket]
   - [sport, basketball]
   - [sport, hockey]
   ```
2. `<%- list_categories() %>` without any parameters enumerate parents and their childs already in hierarchical list; `<%- list_categories(site.categories, {depth: 1}) %>` enum only parents (sport) of site total, etc. Full options for now [here](https://hexo.io/docs/helpers.html#list-categories).