# What is the right way to implement taxonomies (grouped categories) in Hexo?

Tags: javascript, categories, custom-taxonomy, static-site, hexo

I would like to represent books that have authors (note that `author` is a taxonomy), possibly multiple (so the "author" property of a "book" is a list).

I looked at this SO question:
[Grouping categories in hexo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46194621/grouping-categories-in-hexo)

From that, my understanding is that a structure like this:

```
categories:
 - [authors, "X Y"]
 - [authors, "A B"]
 - [authors, "C D"]
```

...or one like this:

```
categories:
 - [authors, "X Y", "A B", "C D"]
```

in each book.md (there is an md file for each book) does the job.

Which of the two is right? Does any of these solutions enable me to query books of a specific author (e.g. "X Y")?

Comment: The answer to your linked issue is seeming proper.

Comment: Thanks @ManishKhedekar so that is the first of the solutions I thought of. How can I query books of a specific author (e.g. "X Y")?

Comment: You may find out helper logic over here, https://hexo.io/docs/helpers.html#list-categories  If not then let me know.

Comment: Please refer to, https://hexo.io/docs/front-matter This has a description of the usage of categories and tags.

Comment: My understanding is that list-categories does the opposite, e.g. listing all the categories or listing categories for a book.

Comment: @ManishKhedekar could you please explain me more thoroughly how I can do this query? The docs don't seem to help much, at least for me, sorry.